# Unable to join Area 51 community

Tags: support, area-51, login, user-accounts, unregistered-users

I tried to join the "Area 51" community to support a proposal, but I have problems connecting to my other profiles. I commit before joining the community and this might have been the problem. I put the personal info and entered in "Meta" (where I am correctly logged in) and verified my email. I am currently an "unregistered user" and when I click on "register" it gave me an error. I also tried the "Join community" and "Sign up" or "Log In" in the Area 51 community, but all the time there is the same error message:

"Unable to log in:
No user found"

I Finished all the solutions I found, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which solutions have your tried so far?

Comment: @bobble I tried to log out and then log in again to stack exchange. I tried to "uncommit" and then repeat the steps. I tried also to see if two accounts were created and ask to merge them, but it seems that the account of Area 51 is not really an account (at least, for the help center). No other ideas found...

Comment: Do any of the [first five questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area51%2blogin?tab=Newest) duplicate your question, which browser are you using?

Comment: Maybe you block cookies, so login can't be completed. Allow cookies and it might be solved. Also, you might be using browser that simply block cookies by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't have the same problem found by the other questions @Rob asked, I still don't know what was the problem. Today I tried again the "log in-log out" and...simply it worked! So I don't know what was but at least I solved it.